# Docker Nodejs - Mapping App Folder to Host Folder - App Fails to launch with cannot find module

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to docker and trying to mount a NodeJS app folder (where the code is deployed) to a host folder.
My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM arm32v6/node:12.16.3-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# TypeScript compile
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "dist/app.js" ]
```

When attempting to run the image with the following command, it fails and the files do not show up on the host folder /tmp.

`docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /tmp:/home/node/app --init -d --name="my-service" arm32/my-img:20200531-1`

The failure log when running docker logs:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/app/dist/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try to check if container has all source code files.

Comment: does `/tmp` contain your nodejs code?

Comment: At startup time the contents of the host directory always replace what's in the image; you cannot use a bind mount on its own to extract content.  You should probably avoid using mounts or volumes for the application's source code or libraries.

Comment: @Rahul the container itself has the source code

Comment: @Adiii I am expecting /tmp to map to the container folder containing the nodejs source code but it doesn't it's empty.

Comment: @DavidMaze Good point. What do you usually do if you want to have different config files for different environments?